# Is it possible to get the line/character position at which a field was found by Serde

Tags: rust, yaml, serde

I am using serde in combination with serde-yaml and I would like to know at which line and optionally position, a specific field has been found by serde[-yaml] when parsing the original input.

For example when parsing:

```yaml
my_first_field: 0
my_second_field:
  nested: test
```

I would like to endup with something a bit like:

```rust
Mapping {
  "my_first_field": {
    value: Number(0),
    line: 1,
  },
  "my_second_field": {
    value: Mapping {
      "nested": {
        value: String("test"),
        line: 3,
      }
    },
    line: 2,
  },
}
```

Comment: I think that currently has to be implemented by the deserializer itself, not by serde. Look for example at this [serde issue](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/issues/637) that comments on the crate [json-spanned-value](https://crates.io/crates/json-spanned-value).

Comment: Is using [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) an option for you to retrieve this kind of information? This tool can be used for your task with the help of the operators `..`, `type` and `line`

Comment: @jpseng unfortunately no. It needs to be done entirely programmatically.

Comment: @rodrigo I went through the issues and I found also related issues in serde_yaml. It looks like there is some ongoing discussions but nothing available out of the box at the moment.